# Bower Update Foundation-Sites Not Working

Tags: zurb-foundation, bower, zurb-foundation-6, yeti-launch

Using Yeti Launch I created a new foundation site.

I now want to update to the latest version of foundation.

Below is a screenshot of `bower list`:

[image]

I've tried `bower update foundation-sites` but its not working.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong and what i need to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything "wrong" per se. Your `bower.json` has the dependency `"foundation-sites": "~6.0.0"` in it. This will update `foundation-sites` up to version `6.0.9`, but Foundation went from version `6.0.6` to `6.1.0` so you can't update further without changing `bower.json`.

I would do the following:

1. Make a backup of your project because when you do `git pull` later it may overwrite customizations you have made.
2. Run `git remote -v` and make sure that `https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites-template.git` is one of the remotes listed. If you haven't touched the remotes, it will be the `origin` remote by default. If it's not there, add it as a remote.
3. Run `git pull origin master` (replace origin with the name of the remote that points to the link in the previous step if it differs). This will merge in the new commits from updates that were made to the template, including updating the `bower.json` dependency to `"foundation-sites": "~6.1.0"`, which will allow you to update.
4. Take care of any merge conflicts that may come up
5. Run `bower update foundation-sites`

The reason I have you do it this way is so that you get all the updates to the template, as well as the updates to `foundation-sites` package. Settings change between versions and just updating `foundation-sites` alone will not add those changes to your `_settings.scss` file.